# Help me figure out how to save the current in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, kinematics, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

In studying quantum field theory, I encountered some difficulty. When considering the scattering diagram of the electron on the muon:

[image]

Must be accomplished current saving $k_\mu j^\mu=0$ where $k=p^{(e),} -p^{(e)}$ but In order to fulfill this condition it is necessary to  $k^2=0$ which in no way can be equal to zero because the photon is virtual. Really $$k^2=(p^{(e),}-p^{(e)})^2=(2m^2-2p^{(e),}p^{(e)}) $$ Moving into a resting system  $$(2m^2-\epsilon^{(e),}\epsilon^{(e)}-p^{(e),}p^{(e)})=2m(m-\epsilon^{(e),})$$ but $(\epsilon^{(e),}>m)$ so $k^2=2m(m-\epsilon^{(e),})<0$   . I can't figure out where I'm wrong.

Comment: You've simply calculated $k^2$ incorrectly, use the definition in terms of $(p_{e'}-p_{e})^2$ and expand this out to see why this is not zero.